# Webstorm - How can jump out of parentheses but stay on the same line?

Tags: webstorm

I like the auto close feature for parentheses, but javascript requires a semicolon at the end of the line. Shift+enter jumps to the next line, but is there a way to move the cursor after the parentheses or to just go to the end of the current line with a shortcut?

Comment: *"go to the end of the current line with a shortcut?"* **End** button on keyboard?